# Разные темы для админа и пользователей

Tags: themes, wordpress

На время работ над обновлением сайта хочу чтобы выводились разные шаблоны для администратора и остальных пользователей.

Сайт на WordPress.

Как это реализовать?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plugin Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/)

Comment: Спасибо!
Похоже оно самое.